# AWS - get email associated with userid

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I hope you are all doing good,

I have a very begginer-question that I couldn't find answer to while looking online. 
I am following a [full-stack Serverless app guide](https://serverless-stack.com/) and here is my issue:

**Problem**: I have a user pool that includes the user who have an account. This userpool contain the email and password of each user. The userpool is stored in 'Cognito'.

I also have a DynamoDB that contains data that users can upload and read. This data is stored under a username(which is a bunch of letters and numbers), so it knows how to associate a data to a specific user.

I am trying to create a web page that contains a table of all the data that all the users have. I manage to get all the data from the DynamoDB (using `aws-amplify`) and this data is keyed with the username(which, again, is letters and numbers). **is there a way to get the attributes of a user in cognito user pool with the given username?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS Cognito API supports the `AdminGetUser` Action and the response includes all user attributes.

You can read more about Cognito’s AdminGetUser action [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html). Note calling this API method requires developer credentials to call it.